# User can not remove from queue after changing the role

Tags: case, user, queue, assignment-rules

We have a Case Assignment rules which is assign to a particular queue and in this queue, there is role 'ABC' added in it. When I change the User's current role from ABC to XYZ, it can not remove user from the queue since user rolr is now XYZ which is not part of any queue.

What could be the reason behind this?

I can not find any docs related to it. It does not even give us an option to manually remove the user from Queue in related list of Users.

Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ABC role reports to XYZ role or XYZ role is at top level in hierarchy then neither Queue gets removed from queue membership nor you remove the queue manually from queue membership. You need to change the role to parallel role of ABC or any other role which reports to ABC role.

Below Salesforce docs explains Queue members and Users higher in role hierarchy can access Queues.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_the_sharing_model.htm&type=5

Hope it helps